# Sort Month text (jan, feb etc.) in multiple year dataset

Tags: powerbi, dax

In Power BI I need to make a visual with a bar chart showing values over 12 months, from jan to dec. However, my dataset has 3 years of daily data, so I cannot sort by another helper column (monthsort) as there are more distinct values in the sort column than the result column.

How can I get an x-axis sorted from jan to dec?

I can make changes either in SQL Server table or DAX in tabular model.

NB: I cannot use date hierarchy, as I use Analysis Services and Live Connection.

Comment: If I understand your requeriment, what you need is show months from Jan to Dec for each year, so first you need to show months for year 1 then months for year 2 and so on for year 3, right?

Comment: I have two slicers, one for years and one for months. In the one for months, I need to just show jan - dec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new column called "DateSort" or something like that and use following DAX formula:

=FORMAT([Date],"YYYYMM")

Select your daily data column and choose "Sort by Column" and set it to "DateSort" column.

Does that work ?